# split big matrix into multiple smaller ones - difficulties

Tags: python

I have a 32*32 matrix and I want to break it into 4 8x8 matrixes.

Here's how I try to make a smaller matrix for top-left part of the big one (**pix** is a 32x32 matrix).

```
   A = [[0]*mat_size]*mat_size

   for i in range(mat_ size):
        for j in range(mat_size):
            A[i][j] = pix[i, j]
```

So, **pix** has the following values for top-left part:

```
198 197 194 194 197 192 189 196
199 199 198 198 199 195 195 145
200 200 201 200 200 204 131  18
201 201 199 201 203 192  57  56
201 200 198 200 207 171  41 141
200 200 198 199 208 160  38 146
198 198 198 198 206 157  39 129
198 197 197 199 209 157  38  77
```

But when I `print(A)` after the loop, all the rows of **A** equal to the last row of **pix**. So it's 8 rows of `198 197 197 199 209 157  38  77` I know I can use `A = pix[:8, :8]`, but I prefer to use loop for some purpose. I wonder why that loop solution doesn't gives me correct result.

Comment: what is `pix[i, j]` ?

Comment: lets me iterate over **pix** list

Comment: You should include, how you created `A`:  `A= [[]]*mat_size`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: `pix` is a 32x32 matrix,  using`pix[i, j]` will get error,  why not `pix[i][j]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
A = np.zeros((4, 4, 8, 8))

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        A[i, j] = pix[i*8:(i+1)*8, j*8:(j+1)*8]
```

If I understand your question correctly, this solution should work. What it's doing is iterating through the pix matrix, and selecting a 8*8 matrix each time. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `numpy` in order to avoid multiple references pointing to the same list (the last list in the matrix):

```
mat_size = 8
A = np.empty((mat_size,mat_size))
pix = np.array(pix)

for i in range(mat_size):
    for j in range(mat_size):
        A[i][j] = pix[i][j]
```

Comment: What difference did it make? Try `pix = np.random.randint(5, size=(8, 8))` and `mat_size = pix.shape[0]` and see what difference you get with `[i,j]` and `[i][j]`

Comment: A[i][j] = pix[i][j]
TypeError: argument must be sequence of length 2

Comment: Try also converting `pix` to a numpy array